# Very small number turns negative in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm doing a program in Fortran90 which do a sum from `i=1` to `i=n` where `n`is given. The sum is `sum_{i=1}^{i=n}1/(i*(i+1)*(i+2))`. This sum converges to 0.25. This is the code:

```
PROGRAM main

INTEGER n(4)
DOUBLE PRECISION s(4)
INTEGER i

  
OPEN(11,FILE='input')
OPEN(12,FILE='output')
DO i=1,4
  READ(11,*) n(i)
END DO

PRINT*,n
CALL suma(n,s)
PRINT*, s

END

 
SUBROUTINE suma(n,s)
INTEGER n(4),j,k
DOUBLE PRECISION s(4),add
s=0 
DO k=1,4
  DO j=1,n(k)
    add=1./(j*(j+1)*(j+2))
    s(k)=s(k)+add 
  END DO 
END DO
  
END SUBROUTINE
```

**input**

```
178   
1586     
18232 
142705
```

The `output` file is now empty, I need to code it. I'm just printing the results, which are:
 `0.249984481688             0.249999400246             0.248687836759             0.247565846142`

The problem comes with the variable `add`. When `j` is bigger, `add` turns negative, and the sum doesn't converge well. How can I fix it?

Comment: @KenY-N isn't `n` initialized in `READ(11,*) n(i)`?

Comment: What are the values in the file `input`? Please add the file to the question. What are the results (the results from `PRINT*,n` and `PRINT*, s`)? Please add to the question as well.

Comment: Is the problem that `j*(j+1)*(j+2)` overflows an integer and goes negative? If `n(k)` is greater than about the cube root of the max integer value, then there might be an overflow, resulting in a negative number?

Comment: @albert they're now added

Comment: @KenY-N yep, when n(k) is greater, 1./j*(j+1)*(j+2) gets negative.

Comment: Not a nice solution at all but maybe write: `add=((1./j)/(j+1))/(j+2)` (Disclaimer, didn't test it).

Comment: @albert now returning ```0.249984481688             0.249999801600             0.249999998496             0.249999999975``` THANKS! Why was it failing?

Comment: It was failing for the reason KenY-N gave, there is an integer overflow in the term `1./j*(j+1)*(j+2) ` so wraping around to negative numbers. Note that you calculation is performed in `real` and not in `double  precision`. better might even be `add=((1.d0/j)/(j+1))/(j+2)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is an integer overflow. 142705*142706*142707 is a number that is too large for a 4-byte integer.

What happens then is that the number overflows and loops back to negative numbers.

As @albert said in his comment, one solution is to convert it to `double precision` every step of the way: `((1.d0/j) / (j+1)) / (j+2)`. That way, it is calculating with floating point values.

Another option would be to use 8-byte integers:

```
integer, parameter :: int64 = selected_int_kind(17)
integer(kind=int64) :: j
```

You should be very careful with your calculations, though. Finer is not always better. I recommend that you look at how floating point arithmetic is performed by a computer, and what issues this can create. See for example [here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems).

Comment: I don't see the real advantage of the int64 bit usage, won't this overflow in `(j*(j+1)*(j+2)` quite fast as well (probably around 2^21, just 2 million)?

Comment: Agree with @albert Unless it is performance critical I think I would just divide by j, and then divide by ( j + 1 ) and then by ( j + 2 )

Comment: If you want to avoid the extra divisions, Fortran offers a conversion intrinsic.  Try `1/(real(j) * real(j+1) * real(j+2))`.  A better option might be to recursively compute the addend:  `a(1) = 1 / real(1 * 2 * 3)` with a(j+1) = j * a(j) / (j + 3)`

Comment: If you really want to avoid divisions I'd pre-calcuate the inverse factors up to the maximum value of n(k), and use a multiply in the inner loop

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a better way to achieve what you want.  I did remove the IO.  The output from the program is

```
% gfortran -o z a.f90 && ./z
   178 0.249984481688392
  1586 0.249999801599584
 18232 0.249999998496064
142705 0.249999999975453

program main

  implicit none  ! Never write a program without this statement

  integer, parameter :: knd = kind(1.d0) ! double precision kind

  integer n(4)
  real(knd) s(4)
  integer i

  n = [178, 1586, 18232, 142705]
  call suma(n, s)
  do i = 1, 4
    print '(I6,F18.15)', n(i), s(i)
  end do

  contains
     !
     ! Recursively, sum a(j+1) = j * a(j) / (j + 1)
     !
     subroutine suma(n, s)
        integer, intent(in) :: n(4)
        real(knd), intent(out) :: s(4)
        real(knd) aj
        integer j, k
        s = 0 
        do k = 1, 4
           aj = 1 / real(1 * 2 * 3, knd)    ! a(1)
           do j = 1, n(k)
              s(k) = s(k) + aj
              aj = j * aj / (j + 3)
           end do 
        end do
     end subroutine

end program main
```